# Error using UITextView in Swift 3

Tags: uitextview, swift3, xcode8

So last night I updated my code to Swift 3. It was using Alamofire, but Alamofire isn't completely supported for Swift 3, so I decided to use URLSession to parse JSON instead. I'm not sure if that's relevant to the error but might as well throw it in there in case.

So I have this backend server set up and it provides a description in String. I am able to get the String, I can print it in the console, add it to a label, but when I use a UITextView it produces this error:

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not using Storyboards and this is how I'm setting up my TextView:

```
let descriptionTextView : UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = ""
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white()
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
}()
```

I'm adding to the view using layoutConstraints and it's working fine. I can see the textview if I add breakpoints.

If anyone has a solution to this problem, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 5 minutes after posting the question, I found the solution to my problem. I guess this is something new that you have to do when using URLSession, I really don't know but what I did was when I wanted to update my TextView, I did this:

```
OperationQueue.main().addOperation({ 
   self.descriptionTextView.text = description as? String
})
```